# How to create a custom implementation of inject method?

Tags: ruby

It looks pretty easy at first. Here is the first code block that I wrote in a few minutes:

```
module Enumerable

  def my_inject(memo=false)
    memo = memo ? memo : self[0]
    self.my_each do |item|
      memo = yield(memo, item)
    end
    return memo
  end

end
```

When the inject method is called with an initial value, it works as expected. But I haven't been able to find a way to make it properly work **without** any initial value.

For example:

```
puts [1,2,3,4].my_inject(0) { |memo, i| memo+i} #=> 10
puts [1,2,3,4].my_inject { |memo, i| memo+i} #=> 11
```

And this is what original Ruby inject method outputs:

```
puts [1,2,3,4].inject { |memo, i| memo+i} #=> 10
```

The Ruby docs says

> If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then the
>   first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.

So how to set proper data type for initial value? Should we have a condition for every data type in Ruby and set a default value for each of data types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you debug Ruby's own implementation you will see that it starts the iteration from the second element in case no default memo is given:

```
> [1,2,3].inject { |m, i| puts "M: #{m} | I: #{i}"; break }
M: 1 | I: 2
```

Therefore your implementation should look like this:

```
def my_inject(*args)
  init = args.size > 0
  memo = init ? args[0] : self[0]

  self.drop(init ? 0 : 1).my_each do |item|
    memo = yield(memo, item)
  end

  return memo
end

puts [1,2,3,4].my_inject(0) { |memo, i| memo+i} #=> 10
puts [1,2,3,4].my_inject { |memo, i| memo+i}    #=> 10
```

The reason for `init = args.size > 0` is you have to take into account that someone might want to do `[...].my_inject(false) { ... }`. Therefore you cannot check if `memo == false` to determine if you need to skip the first element or not, you have to check the actual argument count that was given.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explaining 'false' case. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

> So how to set proper data type for initial value? Should we have a condition for every data type in Ruby and set a default value for each of data types?

No, the default value is the first element of the collection.

Ruby allows you to define your own classes, so writing a case for every possible type is impossible anyway, there are infinitely many of them.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity—tail-recursive solution:

```
class Array
  def my_inject(memo = nil, enum = self.each)
    return enum_for(:my_inject) unless block_given?

    memo = enum.next if memo.nil?
    my_inject(yield(memo, enum.next), enum, &Proc.new)
  rescue StopIteration
    memo
  end 
end

[1,2,3].my_inject(3) { |memo, v| memo += v } 
#⇒ 9
[1,2,3].my_inject &:*
#⇒ 6
```